# Tcl/tk for Mac OS X 10.6, not possible to download?

Tags: macos, applications, install

I've upgraded git today and in its README file I found the following excerpt:

> If you don't already have Tcl/Tk Aqua
>   installed on your computer (most MacOS
>   X installs have it), you will get this
>   error message. To resolve it, simply
>   go to the website for Tcl / Tk Aqua
>   and download the latest version:
>
> http://www.categorifiedcoder.info/tcltk/
>
> If you have an older version of Tcl /
>   Tk Aqua, you'll benefit from
>   upgrading. There have been many
>   usability improvements since the
>   version that comes shipped with MacOS
>   X Leopard.

I tried the link and it redirects to Daniel A. Steffen [LinkedIn page](http://www.linkedin.com/in/danielsteffen/tcltk/), who is the lead developer of Tcl/Tk for Mac, as far as I understand. I tried googling to find alternative links, but they all redirect to the same LinkedIn page. From this I gather that either this alternative version is already included in the Mac OS X, or there is some ongoing conflict. Can anybody enlighten the situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tcl/Tk Aqua is available from this page

http://sourceforge.net/projects/tcltkaqua/

This page has the latest version.

Comment: Pretty bizare, git documentation suggests that installing this version is advantageous, but this version is dated 2005.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, Tcl (beta) is now available as from [ActiveState](http://www.activestate.com/activetcl/downloads)